# GNU Make write to file without shell and without newline

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am trying to come up with a way to write a Makefile almost entirely in pure make for the purpose of being able to easily port it to Windows without depending on sh specific extensions. Want to be able to execute in cmd.exe.

I need to write to a file 5 values separated by spaces, so I do something like this:

```
recipe: $(TARGETS)
    $(foreach target,$^,$(file >> file.txt,$(shell $(target))))
```

The problem is that every execution of `$(file ...)` will add a new line to the file, no matter if I filter out the line, seems to be done after the execution of the function.

Is there any way to accumulate the results of the execution of `$(target)` in a variable in the recipe and later just use `$(file ...)` to just output everything concatenated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "without shell", since you're explicitly using `$(shell ...)` in your recipe.  Anyway without a real-life example we can try I can't be sure, but can't you just invert the order of the `file` and `foreach` functions?

```
recipe: $(TARGETS)
        $(file >>file.txt,$(foreach target,$^,$(shell $(target))))
```

Comment: I should have explained that. Executing a program in any shell is going to be compatible. What I do not want is to pollute the shell with bash or cmd-specific things.